# Display value from associate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I've made a voting system for my app where an user can vote only once for a post that I call "Idee". Here is my association :

**Vote**

```
belongs_to :idee
belongs_to :user
```

**User** `has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy`

**Idee** `has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy`

**Vote Controller**

```
def like
    user = params[:user_id]
    idee = params[:idee_id]
    if Vote.exists?(:user_id => user) && Vote.exists?(:idee_id => idee)
     redirect_to :back, :notice => "Vous avez déjà voté pour cette idée"
    else 
      Vote.create({ idee_id: idee, user_id: user})
      redirect_to :back, :notice => "Merci d'avoir voté"
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<div class="upvote col-lg-2"> 
  <div class="heart-black hidden-xs">
    <p class="like"><%= @idee.vote_id %></p>
    <%= link_to "up", {controller: "vote", action: "like", user_id: @current_user, idee_id: @idee}, :class => "upvote-link" %>
  </div>
 </div>
```

My controller works well, I can upvote and if I already voted I have the notice. Each vote is stored with an user_id and idee_id, but I don't know how can I display in my view the number of vote for each Idee.

I tried something like `vote.idee_id.count`, and I'm not surprise that doesn't work. So there is a way to do what i want ?

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't that far, I tried @idee.vote.count
But what's the difference if there is no "s" to vote ?

Comment: the has_many assocation (an example of a "macro" which is a method which adds lots of methods and perhaps does some other stuff) adds some class methods and instance methods to Idee.  One of these methods is `votes`.  There's no `vote` method.  (If it was a `belongs_to` association it would have `vote` singular.)